# netplan issue with Ubuntu 18.04.1 Server. No network connectivity (no routes either)

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan

I've been using Ubuntu since inception and have recently found out about Ubuntu's switch to using netplan vs it's traditional/better /etc/network/interfaces method.

I'm attempting to get this to work but it simply isn't working.  Based on what I can tell, there is no default route, or possibly even a bad netplan (though ./netplan apply runs correctly). Below is what I'm doing:

- Clean/brand new 18.04.1 install on ESXi
- Interface is named ens160
- My IP Address 247.235.60.161
- My Gateway is 247.235.38.51
- My subnet mask is 255.255.255.255

/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
          ens160:
                  dhcp4: no
                  addresses: [247.235.60.161/32]
                  gateway4: 247.235.38.51
                  nameservers:
                          addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

When I run "netplan apply" it completes successfully.

If I ping 8.8.8.8 I get a "SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable"

If I do a "route" to view my routing table, it returns with nothing.  No routing table.  This definitely is an issue.

If I do an "ifconfig -a" it displays my ens160 interface, correct IP, netmask of 255.255.255.255, no broadcast address, the mac/ether address is correct.

With regards to the addressing/gw/sn, I can confirm that is correct (I have other hosts running with same/similar on this network)

Something is definitely wrong with netplan.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Readers: Please see also the same question on [Ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2405295).

Comment: What is the corresponding /etc/network/interfaces that you would use to configure this?  Because it is not correct to configure a route via a gateway that you do not have a route to, and you do not have a route to anything except your own host because that's what a netmask of 255.255.255.255 means.  So it's ambiguous what you intend here, and it's correct that, given the provided config, netplan is not able to configure a default route.

Answer (score 1):

The gateway must be in your net- With the /32 mask, the gateway is outside your lan. You must configure, for example, a /16 mask. (255.255.0.0).

Answer (score 1):

The subnet configured on the interface does not match your gateway address.
**You should try the “on-link” configuration** which allows you to set up a default route.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    addresses: [ "10.10.10.1/24" ]
    routes:
      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 9.9.9.9
        on-link: true
```

https://netplan.io/examples/